# Convert a collection of raw Landsat 8 scenes to top-of-atmosphere reflectance

Tags: landsat-8, google-earth-engine, toa-calibration

This [link](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/landsat) , use **ee.Algorithms.Landsat.TOA(input)**  to convert a raw Landsat scene to top-of-atmosphere reflectance (TOA). I am trying to convert a collection of raw Landsat 8 scenes (LANDSAT/LC8
) to top-of-atmosphere reflectance (TOA):

```js
//Filter USGS Landsat 8 Raw Scenes base on a point location (geometry)
//then Apply TOA algorithm to the raw collection:
var rawcollection = LC8.filterBounds(geometry); 
var TOA = ee.Algorithms.Landsat.TOA(rawcollection);
```

Earth Engine reply that this is  **Invalid type. Expected: Image**.
So how to apply ee.Algorithms.Landsat.TOA to an ImageCollection?

Answer (score 2):

As the error message suggests, the ee.Algorithms.Landsat.TOA() expects an image, not image collection. If you want to apply this method to images within image collection - [map a function](https://code.earthengine.google.com/91deedd8817bb3a2eddf4f8abdbe8be3), see https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/ic_mapping

Usually, you don't need to run the method yourself, instead, you can use TOA image collections directly. Current recommended Landsat image collection is Tier 1: [image: Landsat 8 TOA Tier 1]